# OAuth in Chrome extension broken in recent Chrome builds

Tags: google-chrome, oauth, google-chrome-extension, doorkeeper

Our Chrome extension has worked flawlessly for months, but broke recently due to oauth failures. We're using our own oauth endpoint (via doorkeeper). The behavior is crazy--when you click the extension button the whole window gets minimized, and when you bring it back to the foreground and accept the oauth prompt the extension popup freezes on the screen, and stays there even when you switch tabs. It doesn't auth, and subsequent calls to the endpoint have 'access_token=undefined' in the querystring. Closing the whole set of tabs is the only way to get rid of the frozen window.

The extension ouath is from https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions. I've read of similar problems in recent version of Chrome caused by different requirement for the manifest--ours is below. The extension works fine if I remove auth entirely.

Have been beating my head against this for days, any help greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "name": "An extenstion",
  "version": "0.5.4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Desc here...",
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },

  "homepage_url": "http://foo.com/button",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Foo Button",
    "default_icon": "img/icon_no_auth.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://foo.com/robots.txt*" ],
      "js": [ "oauth2/oauth2_inject.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://foo.com/*"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "oauth2/oauth2.html"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**Update**: popup.html had been including a file called tracker.js, which contained the code below. Removing it fixed the freezing issue, per my comment below.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: I run into the same issue sometimes when opening the Google Voice extension popup. You should search for similar issues and if none are found, open a new one: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: IT is difficult (if not impossible) to determine the problem if we don't see the code that creates it. Is your extension available at Chrome Web Store ?

Comment: ExpertSystem, apologies--yes, it's here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-entelo-button/nogdppkjhdnlpkbbdbgpmekmbfpkkogb

Note that the manifest above is from my local version, and has been edited while I've been trying to fix this--in particular I added the 'web_accessible_resources' section.

Comment: @JohnMcGrath: I couldn't reproduce the "freezing" issue you described above (maybe OS specific - what OS are you on?). Are there any test credentials (or a way to register for some) one could use for testing out the problematic behaviour ?

Comment: Solved it last night. Turns out the freezing business was being caused by Google Analytics tracking code. Popup.html had been loading a file called tracker.js, which contained the code I just added as an update to the original question. Removing it fixed the 'freeze' issue, and adding the web_accessible_resources block to the manifest fixed the oauth redirection issue. Not sure what Chrome changed to cause this, but I'm guessing something around stricter rules for content injection.

@ExpertSystem, thanks very much for looking at this, much appreciated.

Comment: NP. BTW, feel free (encouraged actually) to post your solution as an answer (and accept it too) in order to help future visitors of the page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestions in the comments, the solution I eventually found.

Turns out the freezing business was being caused by Google Analytics tracking code. Popup.html had been loading a file called tracker.js, which contained the code I just added as an update to the original question. Removing it fixed the 'freeze' issue, and adding the web_accessible_resources block to the manifest fixed the oauth redirection issue.

Not sure what Chrome changed to cause this, but I'm guessing something around stricter rules for content injection.